# Is it enough to avoid xss?

Tags: javascript, xss

When user put 
`<script>alert('Hello');</script>` 
on my site ie on comments section its translated: <script>alert('Hello');</script>
is it enough to avoid xss attack on my site?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: what is translated to what?

Comment: How have you implemented that? Does your site have a search input thats replicated on a search results page?

Have a read of this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Comment: If you submit that form where the comment is in, what happens then? Are you doing a Ajax call to you're backend? e.g. PHP? There are some ways to sanitize you're code, but to give you the correct explanation we really need more information about you're enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert every `<` to `&lt;` and every `>` to `&gt;`, it will prevent the user to enter any html tag. So it is enough.

Answer (score 2):

No its not...the user can change the case of script from lower to upper. He doesn't even need to do that for all letters as well. He can even use body instead of script and display something on load like

lastly, he can even use random things like trying to import and image and if its fails then he will specify what the error action should be.

The best way to get rid all of this XSS client side attack, use Anti-CSRF token.
checkToken( $_REQUEST[ 'user_token' ], $_SESSION[ 'session_token' ], 'index.php' );

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on these Examples too for better security of your website:

1.**Best Possible Security for Reflected XSS**:

```
<?php 

// Is there any input? 
if( array_key_exists( "name", $_GET ) && $_GET[ 'name' ] !=     NULL ) { 
// Check Anti-CSRF token 
checkToken( $_REQUEST[ 'user_token' ], $_SESSION[ 'session_token' ], 'index.php' ); 

// Get input 
$name = htmlspecialchars( $_GET[ 'name' ] ); 

// Feedback for end user 
echo "<pre>Hello ${name}</pre>"; 
} 

// Generate Anti-CSRF token 
generateSessionToken(); 

?>
```

2.**Best Possible Security for Stored XSS**:

```
<?php 

if( isset( $_POST[ 'btnSign' ] ) ) { 
// Check Anti-CSRF token 
checkToken( $_REQUEST[ 'user_token' ], $_SESSION[ 'session_token' ], 'index.php' ); 

// Get input 
$message = trim( $_POST[ 'mtxMessage' ] ); 
$name    = trim( $_POST[ 'txtName' ] ); 

// Sanitize message input 
$message = stripslashes( $message ); 
$message = mysql_real_escape_string( $message ); 
$message = htmlspecialchars( $message ); 

// Sanitize name input 
$name = stripslashes( $name ); 
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name ); 
$name = htmlspecialchars( $name ); 

// Update database 
$data = $db->prepare( 'INSERT INTO guestbook ( comment, name ) VALUES ( :message, :name );' ); 
$data->bindParam( ':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR ); 
$data->bindParam( ':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR ); 
$data->execute(); 
} 

// Generate Anti-CSRF token 
generateSessionToken(); 

?>
```